# why we got same data type in two versions like "int" and "integer" in php?

Tags: php, class, types, backend

I have seen that **int **and **integer **both are do the same job.There is "bool" and "boolean" too.
As i know there is no wrapper classes in php like we have in java.
So my question is, What is the exact purpose of having two kinds like this ?

Theoretically those are may be just two names for the same data types, But i wanna know the answer from you in your experience and your personal opinion on this.
Thank you for your valuable time. Good day to you.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions asking for opinions are off topic here. As well as historical studies. Yes, these are aliases but why PHP introduced them thirty years ago we don't know.

Comment: @Your Common Sense   - thank you sir, So its seams like, its totally up to the developer and depend on the culture they built over the years.

Comment: As it said in the linked questions, you shouldn't use aliases. So it must be short versions: int, bool